# Redis gets stuck in mget

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-webflux

I have spring reactive project and I am using RedisReactiveCommand library to fetch data from redis. I was iterating over number of keys to fetch data from redis using get method. Later on, I move to mget to fetch data altogether for all keys in single time. But after doing mget changes, redis performance degraded. Response time of service has increased.

I moved to mget to decrease number of IO calls but it seems like redis gets stuck in mget which causes increase in response time.
I call mget for number of keys, if data found in redis collect it in list else call backend and save data in redis and collect that too in list and return final list as response.

```
 redis.mget(keys).flatMap(keyvalue -> 
                  if(value is null) call to Backend and return 
                  else return value
).collectList();
```